# Using pg_restore to create or overwrite tables

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, pg-dump, pg-restore

I know this is a weird request, but for some hacky reasons I can't avoid, I'd like to be able to consistently sync a few tables from one database to another. I know I could write out the functionality myself in a script, but I figure `pg_dump` and `pg_restore` will apply a lot of optimizations to the process that I'm not aware of myself.

What I'm wondering is if there's a way to have `pg_restore` overwrite the existing tables. Basically, in pseudo-code something like:

```
-- pseudo code
begin;
drop table to_restore;
drop table to_restore2;
drop table to_restore3;

-- etc

restore table to_restore;
restore table to_restore2;
restore table to_restore3;

-- etc
commit;
```

I'm also open to alternatives ways of doing this if this isn't so great.

Comment: you cant put bash command in postgres transaction

Comment: @VaoTsun hence why I called it psuedo-code. I know I can't, but I'd like to do the equivalent

Comment: either use transaction and let's say `COPY` from to (or fdw, or dblink), or do not in transaction

Comment: @VaoTsun right, but is the equivalent possible with **just** `pg_restore`, and no other extra SQL. What I'm wondering is if I can do with without the need to write my own code other than just calling `pg_restore`.

Comment: if you want to use `pg_restore` - loosing transaction is inavoidable

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seems like you want the `-c` option specified in the [pg_restore documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/app-pgrestore.html)

> -c
>
> --clean
>
> Clean (drop) database objects before recreating them. (Unless --if-exists is used, this might generate some harmless error messages, if any objects were not present in the destination database.)

which you can use with the `-1` flag to do everything in one transaction

> -1
>
> --single-transaction
>
> Execute the restore as a single transaction (that is, wrap the emitted commands in BEGIN/COMMIT). This ensures that either all the commands complete successfully, or no changes are applied. This option implies --exit-on-error.

Comment: Be carefull when restoring partial data. On one occassion a restore operation failed and we thought everything would be rolled back. It took us  some time to understand why we were getting duplicate key value errors when inserting new rows: The sequence table(s) were restored and not rolled back, while no data was restored !

Answer (score 2):

This is only example of possible solution:

copy those tables from first db to csv. and use extremely fast copy in transaction:

```
begin;
truncate table to_restore;
truncate table to_restore2;
truncate table to_restore3;
  set commit_delay to 100000;
  set synchronous_commit to off;
copy to_restore from 'to_restore.csv';
copy to_restore2 from 'to_restore2.csv';
copy to_restore3 from 'to_restore3.csv';
commit;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't helpful to me because I was looking to use **only** `pg_restore`, and not write my own SQL.

Comment: that's right - it is either transaction or `pg_restore`

Comment: You can run pg_restore with the `--single-transaction` option.

Comment: yes multiple `-t` `-c` and `--single-transaction` must do the trick

Comment: This works great except for one situation -- when you need to cascade the truncate/drop. Is there any way to accomplish this via pg_restore?